# Extract numeric and character values from a character variable in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table, character, extract, numeric

I have the following `data.table`

```
df <- data.table(id=c(1,2,3,4),
                 medication=c("Abc de 3 MG", "Afg frt re 4 MG/ML","Agh","Aj yr 5 MG"))
```

with

```
id         medication
1:  1        Abc de 3 MG
2:  2 Afg frt re 4 MG/ML
3:  3                Agh
4:  4         Aj yr 5 MG
```

I want to extract the doses from the medication, and create a column called `doses`

```
id medication   doses
1:  1     Abc de    3 MG
2:  2 Afg frt re 4 MG/ML
3:  3        Agh    <NA>
4:  4      Aj yr    5 MG
```

It should contain the number and unit. Not every medication has a number and unit which should be included as `NA`.

I looked at the `tidyverse` `extract` function but could not find something to extract `numeric` and `character` values.
I am using `data.table` with a large dataset. A time efficient function is great.

Comment: `df[,doses := sub(".*(\\d.*)|.*","\\1",medication)]`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert an `@` (or any other character that is not in your column already) ahead of the first number, then use that to split the column into two:

```
df[, c("medication", "doses") := tstrsplit(sub("([0-9])", "@\\1", medication), "@")]
df

#    id  medication   doses
# 1:  1     Abc de     3 MG
# 2:  2 Afg frt re  4 MG/ML
# 3:  3         Agh    <NA>
# 4:  4      Aj yr     5 MG
```

**EDIT**

A cleanr solution is using slightly more advanced regex (positive lookahead), just need to remember `perl = TRUE`:

```
df[, c("medication", "doses") := tstrsplit(medication, ".(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this method is not data.table, but you can take it into account

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  separate(medication, into = c("medication", "doses"), sep = "(?=\\d)")
# id  medication   doses
# 1  1     Abc de     3 MG
# 2  2 Afg frt re  4 MG/ML
# 3  3         Agh    <NA>
# 4  4      Aj yr     5 MG
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `strsplit` like below

```
df[-1] <- do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(df$medication,"(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s(?=[0-9])",perl = TRUE),`length<-`,2))
```

which gives

```
> df
  id medication.1 medication.2
1  1       Abc de         3 MG
2  2   Afg frt re      4 MG/ML
3  3          Agh         <NA>
4  4        Aj yr         5 MG
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, medication, into = c('medication', 'doses'), '(.*)\\s+(\\d+\\s+\\D+)$')
#   id medication   doses
#1:  1     Abc de    3 MG
#2:  2 Afg frt re 4 MG/ML
#3:  3       <NA>    <NA>
#4:  4      Aj yr    5 MG
```